# Finding the sum of a subset

Tags: python, sum

I have two data sets named folder1 and folder2. The program shows me the target count I want to find and the sum of the values that will reach that target count. However, while I find the folder1 data in seconds, it takes a very long time to find the folder2 data. What should I do to find it in a shorter time?

```py
from itertools import combinations

folder1 = {
    
    "Teoman" : 51.78,
    "Mustafa": 46.93,
    "Celil"  : 18.23,
    "Ayşe"   : 3.07,
    "Hüseyin": 29.32,
    "Leyla"  : 66.53,
}

folder2 = {'10__PYTHON_ENV': 80.29044818878174, '1__YAPAY_ZEKA': 34.33022499084473, '2__ALTYAPI_BORU_HESABI': 0.06213569641113281, '3__BEST_ALGORIYTMS': 10.487943649291992, '4__DENGELEME_HESABI': 0.2784423828125, '5__COIN_ALERT': 9.173674583435059, '6__PYTHON_KURP_HESAPLARI': 6.0962066650390625, '7__SQL_TUTORIAL': 26.39926815032959, '8__2023_02_15_desktop': 165.68173027038574, '9__ICONS': 1.1095151901245117, 'ANACONDA_SETUPS': 2206.1647415161133, 'BEETIND_ODDS': 52.650081634521484, 'BINANCE_KALDIRACLI_ISLM': 0.00225067138671875, 'BLOCKCHAIN': 101.93277072906494, 'CLASS_YAPILARI': 0.014241218566894531, 'DOSYA_BOYUTU_VE_KOPYALA': 0.0019941329956054688, 'EXCEL_VERI_YAZMA_OKUMA': 0.3079366683959961, 'GENETIC_ALGARITYM': 0.01592254638671875, 'GOOGLE_EARTH_DURATION_TIME_PATH': 0.008657455444335938, 'MATPLOTLIB': 0.0037221908569335938, 'MATPLOTLIB_read_txt': 0.0011882781982421875, 'MURAT_OZUN_VIDEO': 403.7390956878662, 'OGRENCI_TAKIP': 175.95281600952148, 'PANDAS_READ_EXCEL': 0.008481979370117188, 'PDF_CREATE': 0.001903533935546875, 'PLOTLY': 0.0038166046142578125, 'pyautocad': 0.844517707824707, 'Py_to_Exe': 251.8494005203247, 'sqlite_db_exam': 0.008614540100097656, 'TAYFUN_SEF': 0.033402442932128906, 'TIRENDAS_AKADEMI': 153.01508235931396, 'TKINTER': 0.00034427642822265625, 'TUGRUL_AILE': 659.8760471343994, 'TURTLE': 0.0038967132568359375, 'TXT_OKU': 0.00572967529296875, 'TXT_OKU_DENEME': 0.0009374618530273438}


def sum_subset(s, items):
    return dict(min((
        c
        for i in range(1, len(items) + 1)
        for c in combinations(items, i)
    ), key=lambda x: abs(s - sum([v2 for v1, v2 in x]))))


sonuc = sum_subset(100, folder2.items())

for i in sonuc:
    print(i,'-->', sonuc[i])
```

I tried with lists but it takes too long again.

Comment: I did not use any threshold. 100 there is the sum of the values that should be found in the list.

Comment: Did it really take seconds when you copied this code as is and tried with folder2?

Comment: Your dictionary is 32 elements, and you are looking at all 2**32 subsets.  This is sure to be a bad, slow algorithm.  What is it you're actually trying to do?

Comment: Hello,
What I'm really trying to do is to get a desired sum over a large data set. So, how can I find a solution for a very large data set?